# Android Studio Chipmunk create Vector drawable from svg, the UI does not work(Process not responding)

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

When Android Studio create Vector drawable from svg, the software UI does not work.The loading icon will be displayed all the time, resulting in no response from the Android studio process. It needs to be forced to exit before it can return to normal.

[image]

MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)(Apple M1 Max)(32G)
[image]

Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.robohorse.robopojogenerator (2.3.5), com.alibaba.p3c.smartfox (2.1.1), org.jetbrains.jumpToLine (0.1.8), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16), PythonCore (212.5712.43), Dart (212.5744), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.6.21-release-334-AS5457.46), izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (6.24), de.ohmesoftware.parcelablegenerator (0.7.1), com.mistamek.drawablepreview.drawable-preview (1.1.5), io.flutter (68.1.2), com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI (6.9.1)